# How to know how long the animation last and how to stop gif at the end in Maple

Tags: animated-gif, maple

How do I know how long an animation lasts and how do I stop the `gif` at the end?

I created a GIF from export tool (Maple) but I don't know how long the animation is, or how to make GIF run in real time. I made a gif for showing how something falls down from an altitude. I need to show some figures like `t(time)` , `h(height),` `v(speed)` while it falls down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands that generate animations in Maple often have an option that controls the default number frames. For example, the [plots:-animate](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots/animate) uses 25 frames. Moreover, animations that are shown in the Maple GUI can be controlled by the [animation toolbar](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/reference/AnimateToolbar), which sets animations to run at 10 frames per second (fps) by default. When you use the right-click menu to export your animation to a GIF file, the exporter will take the current setting for fps into consideration and produce an animation that is 25 frames / 10 frames per second = 2.5 seconds long. Changing this value in the animation toolbar will result in shorter or longer animations accordingly.

From a couple of quick tests, exporting the animation programmatically does not respect the choice of fps, so in this case you may need to play with the number of frames in order to compensate for the default 10 fps setting.

With respect to stopping the gif, as far as I know, there is no way to control this using Maple. I believe that the only solution is to use a GIF editing program to manually turn off the 'loop' option.